# Flutter Could not find the correct Provider<> above Widget when trying to create ExpansionPanelList

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I am trying to build ExpansionPanelList and im using Provider there. To be honest i cannot fully understand the Provider but I am using it as i could not figure other way to make it work. I have seen provider used similar way in somewhere else so i think im not completely wrong here?

Thanks for any help!

```
import 'package:cloud_firestore/cloud_firestore.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:provider/provider.dart';

class Product {
  final String name;
  final String price;

  Product({this.name, this.price});
}

class DatabaseService {
  final CollectionReference productsCollection =
      Firestore.instance.collection('products');

  List<Product> productListFromSnapshot(QuerySnapshot snapshot) {
    // cycle through each document and create product list
    return snapshot.documents.map((doc) {
      return Product(
        name: doc.data['name'] ?? "",
        price: doc.data['price'] ?? 0,
      );
    }).toList();
  }

  Stream<List<Product>> get products {
    return productsCollection.snapshots().map(productListFromSnapshot);
  }
}

class ProductList extends StatefulWidget {
  ProductList({Key key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _ProductListState createState() => _ProductListState();
}

class _ProductListState extends State<ProductList> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final products = Provider.of<List<Product>>(context) ?? [];

    return Container(
      child: ExpansionPanelList.radio(
        children: products.map<ExpansionPanel>((Product product) {
          return ExpansionPanelRadio(
            value: product.name,
            headerBuilder: (BuildContext context, bool isExpanded) {
              return ListTile(
                title: Text(product.name),
              );
            },
            body: ListTile(
              title: Text(product.name),
              subtitle: Text('some text here as subtitle text'),
              trailing: Icon(Icons.delete),
              onTap: () {
                setState(() {
                  products.removeWhere((currentItem) => product == currentItem);
                });
              },
            ),
          );
        }).toList(),
      ),
    );
  }
}


____________________





class Home extends StatelessWidget {
  final AuthService _auth = AuthService();

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: Colors.blue[50],
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('test'),
        backgroundColor: Colors.blue[400],
        elevation: 0.0,
        actions: <Widget>[
          FlatButton.icon(
              onPressed: () async {
                await _auth.signout();
              },
              icon: Icon(Icons.person),
              label: Text('LogOut'))
        ],
      ),
      body: HomeScreen(),
    );
  }
}


class HomeScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  HomeScreen({Key key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _HomeScreenState createState() => _HomeScreenState();
}

class _HomeScreenState extends State<HomeScreen> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Center(
      child: Column(children: <Widget>[
        RaisedButton(
            color: Colors.blue[600],
            child: Text('ProductList'),
            onPressed: () {
              Navigator.push(context,
                  MaterialPageRoute(builder: (contex) => ProductList()));
            }),
      ]),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Where is your problem declared? Is it above MaterialApp, or is it in another route?

Comment: Sorry im not sure what you mean by that? Do you mean where is the code snippet containing the Provider which is causing the error? Its right there on the ProductList widget. --> final products = Provider.of<List<Product>>(context) ?? [];

Comment: I don't mean where you _read_ the provider, but where you _create_ the provider. You likely have a `ChangeNotifierProvider` somewhere.